# Can someone point me to exact details on javax.net.debug?

Tags: java, debugging, ssl, jsse

I'd like to get exact details on the SSL debug output generated using javax.net.debug. I have looked, but nearly everything just goes through a sample file.

Sorry in advance if this is easier to find then I expected.

Comment: I also found this link, but again it doesn't cover everything. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_the_Java_Secure_Socket_Extensions

Comment: "nearly everything just goes through a sample file" means what?

Comment: See http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Javax.net.debug

Comment: [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) and [this](http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Communication-Debug-javax-net-debug.html) may be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

I don't understand what it is that you don't understand.

There's the specification of the option itself in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug). There's the tutorial mentioned by @JavaGeek.

You definitely need to understand the SSL handshake process to understand the output for the handshake option, and your reference for that is [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt), or th excellent book by Eric Rescoria if you like.

You would need to understand the `TrustManager` and `KeyManager` interfaces to make much sense out of the keymanager and trustmanager options, and the `SSLContext` and friends to understand the session and context stuff.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by the exact details?

Oracle provides a pretty good tutorial on [how to debug SSL connections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html), but if you're trying to find the Javadoc for it, I don't think it's available.

Comment: Thanks. I had found that before, but it doesn't appear to cover everything.

Comment: @Jiyeon Doesn't cover everything such as what? It looks complete to me.